# Android emulator: Set mobile device number?

Tags: android, emulation

Does anyone know if its possible to set the emulator's mobile number? I have not been able to find information about this anywhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Mostly full control of the phone number detailed at the end of this blog:

http://blog.talosintel.com/2013/04/changing-imei-provider-model-and-phone.html

First 7 are fully configurable, last 4 can be one of 16 allowed port numbers.

> It turns out that the phone number is stored on the SIM card. Since there is no actual SIM card, one is emulated. This emulated SIM is hard coded in the emulator-arm binary. The reason replacements for 1555521 failed is because SIM cards have a specification that does not store the MSISDN (Mobile Subscriber Integrated Services Digital Network-Number, AKA phone number) in plain text. Instead, each set of digits is swapped in some reverse nibbled endianness nightmare.
>
> ...
> A quick way to find the MSISDN is to search for %d%df%d in the binary (highlighted in red below). The corresponding source code is in external/qemu/telephony/sim_card.c on line 436 in the current repo. The following is the format string portion of that sprintf:

```
"+CRSM:144,0,ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0781515525%d1%d%df%dffffffffffff"
```

> The interesting part is 515525%d1 (highlighted in blue). Swapping each set of two digits produces 1555521%d (thanks again CodePainters). That looks like the prefix to our mobile number.

Edit it in a hex editor.

Answer (score 2):

As I have found each emulator already has a phone number. If you run two emulators you can call from one emulator to another. To find out this phone numbers you can run in the terminal window:

```
Path\To\Your\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
emulator-5556   device
```

First phone number is `+15555215554`, second `+15555215556`, i.e. phone number is prefix `+1555521` plus emulator suffix `5554` or `5556`.

Comment: Is there any way to change the phone number?

Comment: @Nayan You may try this https://proandroiddev.com/android-emulator-change-your-sim-card-number-8c7a72bc185a

Comment: You can also check the phone numbers by looking at the emulator's Settings > SIM status.

Comment: I have no the `SIM status` in `Settings`. Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

I think this webpage will show you how to do it

https://www.wikihow.com/Find-Your-Phone-Number-on-Android

here instead of about phone try searching about the emulator device [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate incoming SMS and calls in the simulator (using the simulator's port) but that's all, you can not set a device number or anything like that. For that kind of thing you will need a real device.

Comment: Can you provide a source of information for that? @ferostar

Answer (score 0):

In your emulated device, press on the 3 dots highlighted in yellow and choose phone and then you can change the mobile number, screenshot attached in link below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhbSV.png

Answer (score -2):

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

                 // get IMEI
                 String imei = tm.getDeviceId();
                 System.out.println("gfvnchgjvbnvhjbbnvgjvbncghvmn ngvm"+imei);

                 // get SimSerialNumber
                 String simSerialNumber = tm.getSimSerialNumber();
                 System.out.println("854755745588954754855ngvm"+simSerialNumber);

                 //get SimCardNumber
                 String number = tm.getLine1Number();
                 System.out.println("gfch5652345651szdxfcgvhbjnfcgvh ngvm"+number);



And Import :]->

import android.content.Context;

import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
```

Answer (score -3):

The mobile number of an emulator is the port number of that emulator. For more details. please check this link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#calling

Comment: looking through that page now, but logically doesnt sound correct... how can you set the port to something like: 3033031234?

Comment: Yes, you cant change the port number to a mobile number.

Comment: How can you set the port number to mobile number ? As ports are 65535 only which is of 5 digits and the mobile number is of 10 digits.