# Why is the directory "external/qemu" missing after cloning the Android source code?

Tags: android, android-source, repo

I cloned the android source code following the instructions at https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading. I want to modify and compile the Android emulator in order to change the phone number to my real one. I found this answer on Stackoverflow where a guy says that I need to modify the file `external/qemu/telephony/sim_card.c`:

> [Android emulator: Set mobile device number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805031/android-emulator-set-mobile-device-number)

The problem is that after running `$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest` and `$ repo sync`, I do have a directory named `external` but inside it there isn't a directory named `qemu`. There's no directory starting with a `q` at all.

So did I do something wrong cloning the sources? Does the emulator reside somewhere else?

Comment: @roland. You would want to build the source code before seeing any executables. Here is what you need https://source.android.com/setup/build/building

Comment: @Dinesh I guess you got me wrong: I do not want to see any executables, I want to modify a certain file, which I cannot find, in order to compile the emulator (i.e. create the executables)

Answer (score 1):

The post you are referring to is from 2013, AOSP move a lot since then and external/qemu is not there anymore.

You can check yourself that there is no "external/qemu" in today manifest [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+/f96b35b9e2fa5ac5b5baf455f68f106968565a20/default.xml).

Answer (score 0):

You can check your `manifest.xml` in `.repo/manifest.xml` to check whether the `external/qemu` is in your repo. If it is yes, your `repo sync` has a problem, otherwise, google has removed it from aosp repo. I check the newest `manifest.xml` in `https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+/refs/heads/master/default.xml`, and it shows maybe google has removed it from aosp repo.

Answer (score -1):

Probably it didn't get synced properly.
Either way you can sync only those that are missing

Try this :

`git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu`

Find more information here : https://android-review.googlesource.com/admin/repos/platform/external/qemu

Comment: Will repo recognize the directory if I run "git clone" without using the repo command?

Comment: I guess you won't have a problem because when building you would be using build script which would crawl all projects and refer the make files.

Comment: I agree with you that the build script will most likely work. But the situation I'm talking about is when the repository is updated: will a "$ repo sync" update the manually cloned repository, too? I don't think so because repo probably won't track this repository as I did not clone it with repo itself.

Comment: I am not very sure about that bro. Let me know if you find something. Would be glad to know about it.

Comment: No, there is no more "external/qemu" in recent aosp.
It will not work to just add an obsolete version to the source tree.